# how to get the current id of show function in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

in my controller in my show function in laravel i want the get the id that shows in browser show when i browse it it shows like this

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/invoices/1
```

i want to get that "1" and use it in show controller like below

```
public function show(Invoice $invoice)
{
    $clients = Invoice::with('user','products')->get();
    $invoice_id = 1;
    $invoices = Invoice::with('products')->where('id', '=', $invoice_id)->firstOrFail();
    return view('admin.invoices.show', compact('invoice','invoices'),compact('clients'));
}
```

and put it instead of $invoice_id so when every my client visit this page only sees the related invoice products . thanks you for help

Comment: How does your route look like? public function show(Invoice $invoice , $id) maybe?

Comment: You already get an Invoice model there, just use `$invoice->id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're actually getting an instance of `Invoice` passed to your `show` method then it likely means you have [Route-Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding) set up for your project. Laravel is looking at the defined route and working out that the ID part (`1`) should map to an instance of `Invoice` and is doing the work to grab the record from the database for you.

The `Invoice` object passed through should refer to an item in your database with the ID of `1`, so to get the ID that was mapped in the route you can simply just do:

```
public function show(Invoice $invoice)
{
    echo $invoice->id; // This should be 1
```

Laravel supports route model binding out of the box these days, but in earlier versions you had to set it up in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`. If you don't want it, try replacing your `show` method signature with this:

```
public function show($id)
{
    echo $id; // Should be 1
```

By removing the type-hint you're simply expecting the value that was given in the route parameter and Laravel won't try to resolve it out of the database for you.

Comment: @thanks jonathon that helped me alot i learned from that cause that was the dark point i could not find :) i had this problem in many other part of project so thanks buddy

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :]

Answer (score -1):

Try using `$invoiceId`

```
public function show(Invoice $invoice, $invoiceId)
{
    $clients = Invoice::with('user','products')->get();
    $invoices = Invoice::with('products')->findOrFail($invoiceId);
    return view('admin.invoices.show', compact('invoice','invoices'),compact('clients'));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

do this if you want to get the url segment in controller.

```
   $invoice_id = request()->segment(3);
```

if you want this in view

```
   {{ Request::segment(3) }}
```

Goodluck!

Answer (score -1):

Usually happens when giving a route name different from the controller name

Example:

```
Route::resource('xyzs', 'AbcController');
```

Expected:

```
Route::resource('abcs', 'AbcController');
```